# Javascript logic switch based on "divisible by 2"

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to create a logic switch in Javascript. The aim is to create a Javascript function which can be used to trigger an even on a button click and turn specific calendar feed on or off. When you click button for the first time it should load the calendar feed, when the same button is clicked for the second time the feed should be turned off, and on if its clicked third time etc.

This is the code so far :

```
function click1() { 
  if (times11 % 2 == 0 )
       {$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', {url: 'https://www.google.com/'});
      times11++;
       }
  else
       {$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', {url: 'https://www.google.com/'});
      times11++;
       }
       }
```

For a reason I am uncapable of figuring out it increments by 2.

Ps: var times11 is defined above using var `times11 = 0;`

Comment: There is no problem with this part of your code. If no other part increments `times11`, the function `click1()` gets executed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var _switch = false;

function click1() { 
  if (!_switch )
  {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', {url: 'https://www.google.com/'});
      _switch = true;
  }
  else
  {
     $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', {url: 'https://www.google.com/'});
     _switch = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd call "_switch" "calendarHidden" for two reasons. 1: It's clear what the state represents and 2: in the absence of other considerations, I prefer to have my clauses be non-negated, i.e. in this case "if (calenderHidden)". But otherwise, this is the solution I'd have come up with.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written should work fine; please post a pared-down example showing it not working for further help. Note that You can simplify/shorten your code slightly with:

```
// In general
function click1(){
  if (++times11 % 2) ...
  else ...;
}

// Specifically
function click1(){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
    (++times11 % 2) ? 'addEventSource' : 'removeEventSource', 
    { ... }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is related to semicolon injection ?
Try this code :

```
function click1() { 
  if (times11 % 2 == 0 ) {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', {url: 'https://www.google.com/'});
      times11++;
       }
  else {
       $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', {url: 'https://www.google.com/'});
      times11++;
  }
}
```